# Помогите с многотабличными запросами (4 таблицы)

Tags: mysql

Привет всем. Есть таблицы со следующей структурой:

```
ships(name(PK), class, launched)
ship_classes(class(PK), type, country, num_guns)
battles(name(PK), date)
outcomes(ship(PK), battle_name(PK), result)
```

помогите со следующими запросами, остальные написал, эти не получаются.

1. Получить все те корабли, которые начались использоваться (launched) после 1980 года, и которые после одной победы (result='won') больше не участвовали ни в одной битве.
2. Получить  все те корабли с именами с буквами "РИ"(like %РИ%) которые участвовали во всех боях, в которых участвовали все корабли одного и того же класса (class) (то есть того класса какого этот сам корабль).
3. Для всех кораблей произведенных в Англии (country = 'England') получить во всех боях, в которых было принято участие, сумму проигрышей (result='loose') и выигрышей (result='won');

Comment: Может вы все-таки для начала попробуете сами?

Comment: я пробовал, у меня 10 запросов, 7 из них получились, а эти 3 нет.

Comment: Это я понял из текста вопроса. Я наверное неправильно выразился. Если "эти 3" не получились, наверное у вас есть варианты, которые вы пробовали. Добавьте их в вопрос, чтобы было понятно, что вы не просто просите сделать за вас работу. Неплохо было бы если вы напишете к каждому запросу что именно там у вас не получилось. Надеюсь на понимание

Comment: select sum(result='won')  as w ,sum(result='lose') as l from (select ships.* from ship_classes inner join ships on ships.class=ship_classes.class where country ='England') 
as a inner join outcomes on outcomes.ship=a.name;  кажется получилось.

Comment: Век живи - век учись. Я такой фокус `sum(result='won')` первый раз вижу. И ведь работает :)

Comment: ну да, и мне в первый раз на ум пришло )))

Comment: Только к чему такие сложности с подзапросом? конструкция `FROM ... INNER JOIN ... INNER JOIN ...` даст то же самое. У вас пример данных есть? Можете сделать фиддл на http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Comment: Согласен. Я еще новичок в SQL. А новички часто не оптимально пишут код :) так вот теперь над 1-ым думаю ))) пока не получается)

Comment: Примера можно сказать нету , это мне для экзамена нужно ))) я просто тестирую на тестовой базе, куда несколько строк просто кинул для проверки правильности

Comment: Что за экзамен?

Comment: По релиационным базам !!!

Comment: Я пока на ночь глядя придумал такой кошмар: `SELECT S.*
 FROM ships AS S
 WHERE S.launched > "1980-01-01" 
  AND (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM outcomes O 
   INNER JOIN battles B ON O.battle_name = B.name
   WHERE O.result = 'won') = 1
  AND (SELECT MAX(B.date)
   FROM outcomes O 
   INNER JOIN battles B ON O.battle_name = B.name) = 'won'` Надеюсь он мне сниться не будет

Comment: не понял концовку?max(date)= 'won' ?

Comment: там три условия 1) начало использования 2) количество побед - одна 3) там у меня ошибка - нужно взять результат последней битвы и он должен быть "won"

Comment: ну вот как раз так и я и не могу взять результат последней битвы)))